# I can't get access to an exposed port in docker

Tags: docker

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and running Python 3.8. Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8

WORKDIR /usr/src/flog/

COPY requirements/ requirements/
RUN pip install -r requirements/dev.txt
RUN pip install gunicorn

COPY flog/ flog/
COPY migrations/ migrations/
COPY wsgi.py ./
COPY docker_boot.sh ./
RUN chmod +x docker_boot.sh

ENV FLASK_APP wsgi.py

EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["./docker_boot.sh"]
```

and my docker_boot.sh

```sh
#! /bin/sh
flask deploy
flask create-admin
flask forge
exec gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000 --access-logfile - --error-logfile - wsgi:app
```

I ran `docker run flog -d -p 5000:5000` in my terminal. And I couldn't get my app working by typing `localhost:5000` but it worked quite well when I typed `172.17.0.2:5000` (the docker machine's ip address). But I want the app to run on `localhost:5000`.

I'm sure there is nothing wrong with the requirements/dev.txt and the code because it works well when I run `flask run` directly in my terminal.

Edit on 2021.3.16:

Add `docker ps` information when `docker run flog -d -p 5000:5000` is running:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS      NAMES
ff048e904183   flog      "./docker_boot.sh -d…"   8 seconds ago   Up 6 seconds   5000/tcp   inspiring_kalam
```

It is strange that there's no mapping of the hosts. I'm sure the firewall is off.

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using 127.0.0.1 instead of 0.0.0.0?

Comment: could you add `docker ps` output for your flask-container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `docker run -d -p 0.0.0.0:5000:5000 flog`.

The arguments and the flags that are after the image name are passed  as arguments to the entrypoint of the container created from that image.

Run `docker ps` and you need to see something like

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE              COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                              NAMES
565a97468fc7   flog               "docker_boot.sh"         1 minute ago     Up 1 minutes    0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp                             xxxxxxxx_xxxxxxx
```